# "to be computed"or"being computed"?

Tags: tenses

I am a little bit confused regarding *to be computed* and *being computed*:

> Each node in this figure is a task that corresponds to an intermediate table that needs **to be computed** and the arrows between nodes indicate dependencies between the tasks.

Or:

> Each node in this figure is a task that corresponds to an intermediate table that needs **being computed** and the arrows between nodes indicate dependencies between the tasks.

Which one is preferred? Why?

Comment: it is trivial but explain me  which one is better one

Comment: Use *to be computed*.

Comment: @Mahnax    : but why?

Comment: I don't really know how to explain it, which is why I didn't post an answer. As a side note, you could simply replace the whole "to be computed" with "computation".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first sentence is fine.  The verb "need" should always be paired with either a noun (I need chocolate) or an infinitive verb (I need to sleep).  So your second sentence is ungrammatical.

You need to use the passive voice in this case, because the subject of "compute" is unspecified.

Comment: Ah, but the whole point of a gerund is that it works as a noun. "Your room needs cleaning" and "this car needs washing" are perfectly grammatical. And in fact, they can't be replaced with "your room needs to be cleaned" and "this car needs to be washed", as those do not express the same thing. The desired degree of cleanliness is different.

Comment: Yes, @RegDwight, you're absolutely right.  But I query the grammaticality of using "being" as a gerund after "need".  What could it possibly mean?

Answer (score -1):

I think neither of your examples are a correct way to phrase that sentence.  The first is using passive voice.

Try:

> Each node in this figure is a task that corresponds to an intermediate table that **needs computing** and the arrows between nodes indicate dependencies between the tasks.

or

> Each node in this figure is a task corresponding to an intermediate table **requiring computation** and the arrows between nodes indicate dependencies between the tasks.

Comment: you says "The first is using passive voice." that means "needs computing" try to create passive vice? yes  or no?

Comment: I mean phrasing such as "needs to be computed" sounds like passive voice to me.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice#For_the_passive_voice

Comment: There's nothing wrong with passive voice.  As @DavidWallace says- The first sentence is fine.